# Ошибка компиляции при добавление кнопки Вверх в Activity

Tags: android, xml

В программе одна `Activity` открывает другую Activity, которая содержит кнопку Вверх.

Однако при компиляции выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{asus.example.com.oop/asus.example.com.oop.Main2Activity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at asus.example.com.oop.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:12)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Как я понимаю, проблема в теме. Использую `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Однако эта тема вроде ж поддерживает `ActionBar`, соответственно, можно добавить кнопку. Тему прописываю в styles и manifest. Поэтому не понимаю, почему не работает.

**UPD**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/loginText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:hint="@string/passwordText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enter"
        android:onClick="onClickButton"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package asus.example.com.oop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickButton(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Main2Activity

```
package asus.example.com.oop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

nav_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/home24"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/person24"
        android:title="@string/account"
        android:visible="true" />
    <item
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications24"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        android:visible="true" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в теме, а в том что у вас программа пытается вызвать `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` - стрелочку возвращения на предыдущий экран и не может ее найти, вернее она не инициализирована, эта строка:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

об этом говорит. Зная Android Studio могу допустить что в логах ошибки можно найти ссылку на строку в классе где вы пытаетесь сделать эту стрелку. У вас там по тексту ошибки почему-то программа пытается вызвать два раза эту стрелку. Вероятнее всего вы пытаетесь создать эту кнопку программно, а тулбар не инициализирован, либо его не видно. Надеюсь я вам чем-то помог, если вы выложите ту часть кода где создаете тулбар, или хотя бы эту кнопку (стрелку) то вам тут более быстро помогут.

### UPDATE

Ознакомившись с вашей разметкой и вашими классами, я пришел к выводу (возможно неверному не спорю) что у вас просто нету этой кнопки и тулбара. То есть у вас каким-то образом идет вызов кнопки которой нету на тулбаре которого нету, хотя я не пойму откуда она вызывается.

Что бы я вам посоветовал: во-первых вам нужно добавить программно на нужную вам активити в классе,для этого вам нужно добавить в разметку сам тулбар:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
        android:elevation="4dp"
       />
```

и дальше его уже добавлять через активити:

```
 mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);
```

вот ссылка на [первоисточник](https://medium.com/@101/android-toolbar-for-appcompatactivity-671b1d10f354), и вот еще один [ресурс](https://devcolibri.com/unit/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-11-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-toolbar-%D0%B8-menu-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-userinfoactivity/). В целом у вас получается так, что вы пытаетесь на неинициализированном тулбаре, создать неизвестную кнопку. И поэтому программа слетает. Если будут какие-то вопросы то не стесняйтесь и пишите, помогу чем смогу, все я думаю помогут. Удачи:)

Comment: сейчас в это возможно трудно поверить, но еще пару лет назад никто никакого тулбара не знал, был простой и понятный экшенбар, который не надо создавать в разметке, а достаточно использовать тему с .*ActionBar ...и все прекрасно работало

Comment: @pavlofff, я видел примеры с `ActionBar` но на ресурсах где я видел эти примеры, было написано что лучше использовать тот вариант который я дал в ответе, так как экшенбар вроде как устарел. Я надеюсь то что я написал в ответе не ересь, потому-что я пока не очень хорошо умею читать и разбирать чужие ошибки)) с учетом того что я еще и со своими ошибками иногда прихожу сюда :)